# How can I add 1 to the parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im stuck with this very simple code were I'm trying to create a function that takes a parameter and adds 1 to the result and returns it but somehow this code gives me no results. (I've called the function to see if it works.)

Somebody please help me since I'm very new to python :)

```
def increment(num):
    num += 1
a = int(input("Type a number "))
increment(a)`
```

I changed it to

```
def increment(num):
    return num + 1
a = int(input("Type a number "))
increment(a)`
```

but still no results are showing after I enter a number, Does anybody know?

Comment: [the `return` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement)

Comment: [the `print` built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)

Comment: As @DonkeyKong said: This code makes no attempt to show anything. You'll need to `print` the result.

Answer (score -1):

You need to ensure you return the num in the increment function and assign it to a.
Return:
    def increment(num):
        return num + 1

Assign:
    a = increment(a)

Comment: if they are passing through parameter a as num wouldnt you do a = increment(a), where increment returns num + 1 and not use a global. I am confused as what you are trying to say by the example. Anyway hopefully I have edited answer to make it more explicit.

Comment: ah my bad! I was trying to reformat my comment on the other answer not yours

Comment: That's alright, I'm still learning so just getting feedback where I can!

Comment: we never do stop learning haha

Answer (score -1):

You need to return some value or it never will appear.

```
def increment(num):
    return num + 1
a = int(input("Type a number "))
increment(a)
```

Comment: this is incorrect, you are not modifying the variable outside the scope of the function, you would need to use the global keyword

Comment: Example of it: [NoReturn + Return + Global](http://postimg.org/image/gmvxkrhdh/)